# Trying to create a couple of links below text in bootstrap footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code:

```
<div class= "footer">
        <p class="pull-left">Copyright 2013</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn-danger btn pull-right">Subscribe</a>

</div>
```

I am trying to place two links nicely spaced underneath the 'Copyright 2013' text in the footer. But everytime I try, even with 'pull-left', the links appear directly inline after it, with no space.

These are the links:

```
<p><a href="#">Terms</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Affiliates</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the subscribe button to stay where it is, just move the pull-left into a div, the copyright in a p, and place whatever links you want underneath, e.g.:

```
<div class= "footer">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <p>Copyright 2013</p>
        <p><a href="#">Terms</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Affiliates</a></p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn-danger btn pull-right">Subscribe</a>       
</div>
```

JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/QWbAa/1/

Or, alternately, to keep them separate:

```
<div class= "footer">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <p class="pull-left">
        Copyright 2013</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn-danger btn pull-right">Subscribe</a>
  </div>   

  <p><a href="#">Terms</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">Affiliates</a></p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QWbAa/

Comment: Cheers :) If you wouldn't mind an up-vote, it would be appreciated!